# CommonsMultipartFile - FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, file, file-upload

I am trying to develop an application where user will upload a file from screen, the file will be processed in server side.
I am using Adobe Flex for UI, Spring 3.2 as middle-ware and Java 5. I can successfully upload the file and in server side and can get the file name. But when I am trying to get the `InputStream`, I get the `FileNotFoundException`. It seams it is trying to create a temporary file in some location inside the application server and trying to read that temporary file for processing, but failed to create the temporary file. Following is the code snippet where I tries to get the file -

```
public List<TransactionVO> populateVO(VoucherUploadCommandForm object,
Connection conn) throws XenosException {
   log.debug("InVoucherVOPopulatorForExcelUpload.populateVO()");
     if(object == null){
     log.debug(" No file uploaded :(");
   }else{
     CommonsMultipartFile file = object.getFileName();
     log.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Excel file uploaded :)");
     log.debug("Excel file= "+ file.getOriginalFilename());
     try {
        log.debug("Excel Size= "+ file.getSize());
        log.debug("Excel fileItem= "+ file.getFileItem().getInputStream());
     } catch (IOException e) {
         log.error(e);
     }
   }
   return null;
}
```

The stackTrace of the error is as follows -

```
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\work\Catalina\localhost\rui-1.1-xenos\upload_375f4172_d416_4ae2_975f_bc5e908a8303_00000007.tmp (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.readObject(DiskFileItem.java:663)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:946)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1809)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1908)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1832)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1908)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1832)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1441)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:942)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:637)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:438)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4358)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:556)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:491)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1206)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Nov 25, 2013 2:56:18 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8084
Nov 25, 2013 2:56:18 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Nov 25, 2013 2:56:18 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/20 config=null
Nov 25, 2013 2:56:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 45220 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

Configure your `CommonsMultipartResolver` to use something other then the default directory. For this set the `uploadTempDir` property of the `CommonsMultipartResolver`.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="uploadTempDir" value="d:/temp" />
</bean>
```

A note on your code, you should be programming to interfaces and not concrete classes. In your controller change `CommonsMultipartFile` to `MultipartFile`.

In your code you are retrieving the underlying `FileItem` directly, you should be using the `MultipartFile` convenience methods for that. You can simply call `getInputStream()` on the `MultipartFile` instance you have.

```
public List<TransactionVO> populateVO(VoucherUploadCommandForm object, Connection conn) throws XenosException {
    log.debug("InVoucherVOPopulatorForExcelUpload.populateVO()");
    if(object == null){
        log.debug(" No file uploaded :(");
    }else{
        MultipartFile file = object.getFileName();
        log.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Excel file uploaded :)");
        log.debug("Excel file= "+ file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            log.debug("Excel Size= "+ file.getSize());
            log.debug("Excel fileItem= "+ file.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes... I just used CommonsMultipartFile for testing purpose. Once done I will use MultipartFile

Comment: Its not working.. I faced the same problem here. The only difference is now its using my specified path.

Comment: Is your tomcat allowed to write to the given directory? Instead of `getInputStream` what happens if you use `getBytes`? Basically it is weird because first the file is checked to exist, could there be something corrupting your file a virusscanner for instance?

Comment: Ah... You shouldn't be calling `getFileItem()`, the `MultipartFile` interface has convenience methods for `getInputStream()` and `getBytes()` you better use those. This is due to the fact that there doesn't have to be a FileItem (yet) because it still is in-memory instead of streamed to disc.

Comment: This was also already part of my initial answer :). So if that helped please accept/upvote.